# Converting from Task[Either[A, Task[B]]] to Task[Either[A, B]]

Tags: scala, scala-cats, side-effects, monix

I am using monix for side effects and ended with this type

`Task[Either[A, Task[B]]]`, Is there a way to get `Task[Either[A, B]]`?

So far all I could do is convert `Task[Either[A, Task[B]]]` to `Task[Any]`, basically removing `Either` using pattern matching and flattening, but missing type information in process

```scala
val tEitherT: Task[Either[A, Task[B]]] = ???

val finalType: Task[Any] = 
tEitherT.map(either => {
  either match {
   case Right(value) => value      // Task[B]
   case Left(value) => Task(value) // Lift    
}  
}).flatten
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import monix.eval.Task
import cats.implicits._
import cats.Traverse

trait A
trait B

def tEitherT: Task[Either[A, Task[B]]] = ???

type EitherRight[T] = Either[A,T] // or use kind-projector plugin instead

val finalType: Task[Either[A, B]] = 
   tEitherT.flatMap(Traverse[EitherRight].sequence(_))
```

In scala 2.13 or with option `-Ypartial-unification` you can simplify to `tEitherT.flatMap(_.sequence)`. See second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52358347/traversing-either-in-scala).

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
tEitherT.flatMap {
  case Right(taskB) => taskB.map(Right(_))
  case Left(a) => Task(Left(a))
}
```

[Try it out!](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/kGZPdjj/0)

Comment: Maybe use `Task.now` for the left case